# jquery load(), stop refresh the page after success

Tags: jquery, get, load, reload

Just a normal load function, but after it finishes, it seems to reload the whole page. This is a simplified version:

```
<body>
    <div id="outer">
         <script>
               $(document).ready(function(){
                   alert('begin')

                   $("#portfolio").click(function(){
                        $("#inner").load("portfolio.html");
                        alert('finish')

                   });
              });
         </script>

         <header>
              <a href="" id="home">name</a>
              <a href="" id="portfolio">portfolio</a>
         </header>

    </div>
    <div id="inner"></div>
</body>
```

All I have written in the portfolio.html document is a line of text, but later it will become more full content. The alerts were just to confirm what was happening.

I have also tried the loading content with the $.get method (which btw didn't work at all...) but all the same reloaded the page.

Is there some sort of stop function that needs to be written? But from what I've read, there is usually no need. This is supposed to be really simple...

Comment: you can just add `#` to `href` like this `<a href="#" id="portfolio">portfolio</a>` or use http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You seem to have `href` set to nothing. Thats why its refreshing. Set it to `#`.](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/XPTF9/) Also, You're missing `e.preventDefault`. Try to add that in the `click` of `#portfolio`.

```
 $("#portfolio").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); 
   $("#inner").load("portfolio.html");
   alert('finish')
 });
```

Comment: Goodness, I didn't notice, I took the # out. Thanks.